# Ember.TextField submit on keyup event

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have Handlebars view with the following search input field:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="controller.query" action="submit"}}
```

when a user presses 'Enter' from the search input field, we make a call to an external API, get response, and query the results accordingly. Here is the code of the (simplified) version of the controller:

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  submit: function(query) {
  // call to external api
  // get response
  // update some values
  }
});
```

How do we trigger "submit" function on the keyUp event instead of 'Enter'? In other words, can the "submit" function in the controller be re-run every time user adds or removes a character from the input field?

Answer (score 0):

going by [this](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/), i think you could add

```
keyUp: function(evt) {
  this.get('controller').send('submit'); 
}
```

or maybe

```
keyUp: function(evt) {
  this.get('controller').send('submit', this.get('controller.query')); 
}
```

to your view (or rather a view extending `Ember.TextField`).

another possibility might be to work with `{{action "submit" controller.query on="keyUp"}}`, but i'm not quite sure how to combine that with the `{{view}}` helper.

Comment: I don't believe you can do on="keyUp" for the view, like you mentioned. As far as the first two solutions go, the keyUp: function(evt) { // } doesn't fire when I type in the textfield. Reading the reference to the Ember guides you sent my way makes me believe I need to extend Ember.TextField and add some sort of custom keyUp attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you use

hbs:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="controller.query"
                       action="submit" class="my-input"}}
```

then in  the view you need to subscribe to `keyUp` event. Since events fire up on whole view (in this case only for elements that support this type of event, inputs, content editable, etc inside the view), you need to check for the input you are looking for.

js:

```
App.ProductsView = Ember.View.extend({
  keyUp: function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('my-input')) { // you can use other identifier
      this.get('controller').submit(e.target.value);
    }
  }
});
```

Another idea is to extend `Ember.TextField` class:

hbs:

```
{{view App.ProductTextField valueBinding="controller.query"
                            action="submit"}}
```

js:

```
App.ProductTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  keyUp: function (e) {
      this.get('controller').submit(e.target.value);
  }
});
```

Actually you don't need to pass parameter to `submit` method from view, since controller has this information already up to date in `query` variable.