# When developing an Ember addon how do I get the custom event paste to work?

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

It is well documented on how to add the custom paste event to an Ember Application. See [custom events](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_customEvents), as detailed in [How to listen to a paste event on a textarea in emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369990/how-to-listen-to-a-paste-event-on-a-textarea-in-emberjs).

My question is how do I achieve this in an Ember addon that I am writing? As I do not see a `Ember.Application.create`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should go into the `included` hook of your addon index.js file.

The included hook will receive the app as an argument and then you should be able to set it's customEvents attribute like:

```
// index.js
module.exports = {
  name: 'your-addon',
  included: function(app, parentAddon) {
    app.customEvents = {
      paste: "paste"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Do I still need a ```this._super.included(app);``` in the included call?

Comment: okay then could you try to create an instance-initializer in your addon and in the `initialize` function do someting like: application.customEvents = {
      paste: "paste"
    }