# Ember add customEvents

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember 2.9 and would like to use the "paste" event.

How I can add paste as an customEvent on start up the application:

This is my current app.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from './resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember-load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

let App;

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you check the guides ==> https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.0/classes/Application/properties/customEvents?anchor=customEvents

Comment: He has mentioned that he is using Ember 2.9 and the one you mentioned is available in Ember >=3.0. If following link could you help you out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369990/how-to-listen-to-a-paste-event-on-a-textarea-in-emberjs

Comment: yes i read the guides and do some experiments, but nothing is helping :(. 
no i cant change to 3.0 i must use 2.9.

i try to add customEvents in the extend-part, on Ember, on App. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I've setup a demo Ember.js 2.9 app at https://github.com/bartocc/stackoverflow-2176861 that demonstrates the code below.

Here's is an example `app.js` to configure the Ember.js to listen to the `paste` event:

```js
// /app/app.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from './resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember-load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

let App;

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver,

  // This is how you make your ember app listen the paste event
  customEvents: {
    paste: 'paste'
  }
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);

export default App;
```

Find more information in [the Ember.js 2.9 API](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/2.9/classes/Ember.Application).

Then, make any component listen to the `paste` event with:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  paste(event) {
    const text = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    alert(`you've just pasted the text '${text}'`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't be a simple `addEventListener()` be a more future proof solution? Especially cause there are no event hooks on `@glimmer/components`, which will be the default component base class in Ember Octane.

Comment: as for Octane, I tend to agree with you @jelhan, but the OP question is about Ember.js 2.9

Comment: But using `addEventListener()` should work in Ember 2.9 as well.

Comment: this solution works. but now i have a new problem. the paste event is triggered before the text appears in the input element. 
what i tried is to write the text from clipboard into the element and then fire the event. nothing changes. it remains empty.
what i still used is key-up because then the text is also available after the key is released. how can i realize such a thing with paste?

Comment: your original question was about how to use the `paste` event @Zaphot. To keep things clear, you could probably create a new stackoverflow question with your new issue and post your own answer there.

Comment: Sorry, I have lost the focus of the assignment. I have delete this answer.